# Number of process and Currency and Pool Size in Celery

Tags: python, celery, celeryd

In celery 3.0, what are the relationship among Max concurrency, number of actually running processes and pool size ?
I run celery with max-currency( -c ) set to one and three celeryd processes pops up. I do not know why.